# Xamarin.forms authentication PKCE

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth, identityserver4, pkce

I have an Identity server 4 application which i am trying to login to using my Xamarin.forms app using PKCE.  I keep getting an error from the identity server one that i have actually not seen before. `code_challenge is missing` I am guessing that i am using the wrong grant type but all the documentation i have found for Xamarin says i should be using this one.

How do you connect Xamarin to Identity server 4?

## The error

> ```
> fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
>       code_challenge is missing
> {
>         "ClientId": "xamarin",
>         "ClientName": "eShop Xamarin OpenId Client",
>         "RedirectUri": "1046123799103-h63f9o1cnj78fo26okng1aacr9e89u2e:/oauth2redirect",
>         "AllowedRedirectUris": [
>           "http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc"
>         ],
>         "SubjectId": "anonymous",
>         "ResponseType": "code",
>         "ResponseMode": "query",
>         "GrantType": "authorization_code",
>         "RequestedScopes": "",
>         "State": "egfczresvcjyeerw",
>         "Raw": {
>           "client_id": "xamarin",
>           "redirect_uri": "1046123799103-h63f9o1cnj78fo26okng1aacr9e89u2e:/oauth2redirect",
>           "scope": "profile openid nol_api navinfo",
>           "response_type": "code",
>           "state": "egfczresvcjyeerw"
>         }
>       }
> ```

## Client id in Identity server

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "xamarin",
                ClientName = "eShop Xamarin OpenId Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" },
                RequireConsent = false,
                RequirePkce = true,
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:8008/Account/Redirecting" },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "navinfo",
                    $"{nolConfig.Client}_api"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireClientSecret = false
            }
```

## xamarin code

```
Authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator
            (
                _clientId,
                _secret,
                _scopes,
                new Uri(_discoveryDoc.AuthorizationEndpoint),
                _redirectUri,
                new Uri(_discoveryDoc.TokenEndpoint),
                null,
                isUsingNativeUI: true
            );
```

If I remove  `RequirePkce = true,` from the client in the identity server I no longer get the error in question.  From what I have been able to find it would seam that Xamarin.auth doesn't support PKCE yet.  Which means i will either have to disable it or implement it myself.

How do Login to Identity server 4 from XAmarin forms with PKCE enabled.

Comment: did you ever get a solution how to use Xamarin.auth with pkce?  I am needing to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PKCE is enabled in `OAuth2Authenticator` by not having a client secret:

```
    protected bool IsProofKeyCodeForExchange
    {
        get
        {
            return
                accessTokenUrl != null                    // AccessToken url is defined
                &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret)   // Client Secret is not defined
                ;
        }
    }
```

So I would try

```
Authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator
        (
            _clientId,
            null,
            _scopes,
            new Uri(_discoveryDoc.AuthorizationEndpoint),
            _redirectUri,
            new Uri(_discoveryDoc.TokenEndpoint),
            null,
            isUsingNativeUI: true
        );
```

Comment: Tried it still getting the same error message.  Your right it looks like it should be supported